# Geofence is not triggering after power saving mode

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, geofencing, google-awareness

I am using geofence in my app and it is working fine without power saving mode.

After power saving mode geofence is not triggered.

I added again but it is not worked. I was trying BroadcastReceiver and IntentService but this is not worked too.

I was followed [google sample](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) instructions step by step but this is not worked too.

How do I get it triggered after power saving mode?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#reduce-power-consumption)?

Comment: Yes i read. Actually i am using 'Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS'  So my app is not optimized for battery.

Comment: So how can you think it works properly?

Comment: I may have said wrong before. Normally it works very well. It's triggered immediately. When I switch to power saving mode, it works well first. But after waiting for half a day I could not trigger him in any way.

Comment: I agreed but it reacts accordingly if your app optimized for saving mode.

Comment: Make sure that in power saving mode your location mode is `High accuracy` its depends on it @Mustafa

Comment: I mean i am using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS).
So i expected power saving mode must not block my jobs.

Comment: @TanveerMunir thanks for suggestion for high accuracy. It is in high accuracy mode and still doesn't work.

Comment: have look at [this](https://simpleinout.helpscoutdocs.com/article/232-my-geofences-arent-working-android). its shows that your power saving mode affects your location accuracy mode which is necessary for geofencing.

Comment: I am really appreciate for this conversation. Thanks for your help. As i understand there is no solution for power saving mode.

Comment: For nowadays you can say that